# Should queriers of etymology declare awareness of linguistic traps?

Tags: discussion

[This meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/why-unclear-how-does-but-for-mean-if-it-were-not-for?noredirect=1#comment24069_6782) motivated this. By linguistic traps, I mean those listed at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/12077/5306, such as the Etymological Fallacy.

For me, though it'd be easier not to,  I repeat that 'I heed the Etymological Fallacy'. In  the past, questions have been closed because the closers might have thought that the poster didn't know about it. On the contrary, I do 'heed' these traps and want to state this outright, to anticipate repliers' concern and to forestall extra (redundant) writing on these traps (for each question).

Comment: I didn't need to see the question to know who asked it! I knew it when I saw the title in the list.

Comment: You *keep saying you heed it*, but then you proceed to demonstrate that you *ignore it* in every single case. This is worse than ignorance, it is willful, flagrant, ignorance.  You want a word to *make sense* based on its history and origins, but words *are not so obliged*, and I, for one, wish you could simply accept that. Your insistent linking of this [one off-hand comment](http://bit.ly/1GthtCW)  comes across as a desperate clutching at straws.

Comment: I don't think you're using 'heed' the way everyone else uses it. It doesn't mean 'be aware of' or 'take into account'. It means 'to follow' or 'listen and act upon'.

Comment: @DanBron What about the advice at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205571/how-does-be-of-combine-to-mean-possess-give-rise-to#comment485482_205571? My goal is just to follow that advice, but can I follow it without being ignorant of linguistic traps?

Comment: I know you don't want to memorize words, but in reality the best -- possibly only -- way for you to internalize the meanings of words is through repeated exposure (aka practice!).

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: I haven't even read your question yet: it was just funny to recognize your hand in the title alone.

Comment: @DanBron I'll just respond more slowly then. I write 'I heed ...' because I was trying to be concise, and [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heed) says: Pay attention to; take notice of. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Law You can probably tell from Mitch's and my previous comments that we do **not** feel that one comment justifies your use. We feel that you should *follow*, not just *be aware of*, the etymological fallacy. In other words: give up the ghost. Words mean what they mean, today, *without regard to* where they come from. A bough may start out as a shoot, then a twig, then a stick, then a branch, zigging and zagging and twisting and turning the whole way, until its uttermost point is a great distance from where it emerged at the trunk, based on the whims and vicissitudes and accidents of history.

Comment: @Law, did you see my [original comment under your question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/should-queriers-of-etymology-declare-awareness-of-linguistic-traps?noredirect=1#comment24080_6791)? The one where I said "*Your insistent linking of this one off-hand comment comes across as a desperate clutching at straws*"? Does that clarify my position, here? Does it help clarify further when I note that you've linked to that single comment no less than three times in this one discussion already?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Dictionaries aren't perfect. That definition of 'heed' may work in some circumstances, but not in this one. The more common usage is 'to follow'. So every time you say "I heed the X fallacy" It sounds really weird and out of place, like you are claiming that you always try to _commit_ the X fallacy (which is the opposite of what you want).

Comment: To answer your question, no, it's not necessary to declare awareness of every possible error. But mentioning how you've considered it may help. Re the etymological fallacy, you may want to say you've seen the etymology and wonder if that informs the current meaning (it's only a fallacy if they don't match, and sometimes the history of a word _does_ tell you the current meaning, you've only committed a fallacy when it doesn't match).

Comment: @Mitch No.  No, no no no no.  NO.  The fallacy is *believing they **should** match in the first place*. If the word is new enough, or its history straightjacketed enough, such that the meaning and the origin haven't diverged, so well and good.  That simply is NOT the case with most words which have been around any meaningful amount of time. In general, we should *not expect* a word's meaning to reflect its ultimate origins, and the further back we trace it the less it should look like it does today. Believing - or in Law's case, insisting - otherwise, is to commit the Etymological Fallacy.

Comment: @Mitch (And if that previous comment seems particularly adamant, it is, because you're further encouraging a user in a behavior he's already finding counterproductive and limiting, which, given his particular volume, is also impacting the site as a whole.)

Comment: @DanBron Thanks. I apologise for missing your edited comment; I didn't see it after you had edited, but now yes. About that linked comment, its status as a comment shouldn't affect its truth. So I'm clutching to it as a sound explanation, and not as a straw man. What if I do find that advice helpful?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit: What advice? Do you mean "You can't derive an idiom's meaning from its parts"? That's not appealing to etymology (the historical meaning of a term), that's saying that some terms mean more than the literal meaning of its parts combined. (I don't know a name for that as a fallacy other than saying ('it's literal' vs 'it's an idiom')

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit If you do find that advice helpful, good for you. I think what you're getting at is not specific to etymology or idiom, but that you want to show that you've 'done your homework' on your question. And the only advice I can give here is that you should show the homework you've done, rather than just claim "I have done my homework". The latter doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @Law Its status as a comment effects its weight. It's one man's opinion, shared in an explicitly ephemeral context, at low cost to the commenter (the comment was 44 words; at 70 wpm, that cost Ben about 45 *seconds* to type). By contrast, you have the weight of [this Wikipedia article](http://bit.ly/1EkdYk3), with *scores* of contributors, as well as *hundreds* of other pages on the internet taking a stance contrary to that one, single, ephemeral, comment. In other words, you may find the comment "the Earth is flat" *helpful*, but you also may wish to consider other opinions.

Comment: @Law Put more briefly, I believe that you find Ben's comment helpful *because* it supports your belief and stated desire that *words should make sense*, despite all the other advice people have repeatedly given you contrary to that position, and that your repeated statement "*I heed the etymological fallacy*" is your way to acknowledge that *you've been presented with* that admonition while simultaneously *dismissing it*. My current advice is: *don't dismiss it*, embrace it, internalize it, and yes, its necessary corollary that you'll need to memorize a bunch of words and idioms.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks again. By 'advice', I actually just meant that on diction: how I ought to use 'consider' instead of 'heed'.

Comment: @Law The field of etymology exists for a reason; I do not minimize it. But I do not believe that reason is to help people confused by a word understand its current meaning. I do not agree that, with the specific kinds of words and idioms which confuse you, as an individual, etymology will "often" help. I think you, as an individual, would be best served by giving up, letting go, and repudiating that particular tenet, and consigning yourself to grasping meaning by encountering these beasts in their natural context. I recommend you learn through repeated exposure. Through deliberate practice.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks. I see now that your and my discussion centres on http://english.stackexchange.com/a/24102/50720, with which (it appears) you disagree? I shall ponder your advice, but if etymology really does help me and I continue to ask about it, can we agree to disagree (only on this point)? We already agree on the illogicality of language and words.

Comment: @Law The very existence of *this* question, here, on Meta, is evidence that that one comment is **not** helping you! It is misleading you! It is leading you down the primrose path to perdition. Your belief that etymology *should* help you (supported by a single comment, the only comment anyone has ever made in support of that myth) is prohibiting you seeing etymology is *not* helping you. In other words: you are ***trapped in the very fallacy you profess to "heed"***! I am offering, have offered, and will continue to offer you a ladder out of that abyss: each rung is an instance of practice!

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for your concern. What of the explanation using etymology for 'to tally' [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/24102/50720)? It helped me to understand the underlying theme of all those definitions. The other feedback there also recommend etymology. Again, I know that etymology only helps some of the time.

Comment: @Law This is getting way too long for a comment chain now.  The problem is your belief that etymology *should* help, is the issue, because you're using it as a crutch to avoid the painful truth that the only path to fluency involves a significant amount of memorization and deliberate practice.  Am I saying that training wheels which have a reputation for falling off at the worst possible moment *never* help you learn to ride a bicycle? No. I'm suggesting there's a better way to learn to ride a bike, be it risky, scary, and arduous.

Comment: Follow the light.... [you are leaving the tunnel](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241579/how-did-the-old-french-rejoindre-mean-a-retort-only-in-english#comment521534_241579).

Comment: Are you the same person as Area 51 Detective Fiction? You really should pick a better name. Your name is too long, doesn't get displayed correctly, is hard to refer to, and frankly, advertising other sites there is just silly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry for the confusion. I have meant to ask: Did you see my response to you at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6782/why-unclear-how-does-but-for-mean-if-it-were-not-for#comment24072_6782? Please confirm, because my response is not actually the foregoing, but rather in that link.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not, no. I shall revert my name to my original; I just hope that Law Area 51 succeeds.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I hope it succeeds too, I'm one of the subscribers!

Comment: @DanBron Yes; I agree about the length. Please message me if you wish to discuss further. Maybe we can continue with the 'chat' feature? I just realised that our discussion resembles http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22776/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-curiousdannii.

Comment: @Law For the most part, I participate in SE using my phone (hence the surfeit of comments and dearth of answers you see from me). That makes it difficult to engage in the kind of real-time exchange expected of chat. That said, *something* about your pattern of questions, of the things that confound you, not just here on EL&U but on other stacks where we've encountered each other, something I can't *quite* put my finger on, really fascinates me. I mean *really*. I also greatly admire the way you conduct yourself here. So if I get time, I may write up an answer for you to this question.

Comment: @DanBron Many thanks! I value your patience and generosity too. Actually, I ought to have clarified that I wasn't expecting an answer from you, but I just wanted to show you two others users' similar chat to ours. To clarify again, this comment needs no response. Please don't fret about replying to my OP either.